# What is the non-light syntax for recursive let bindings?

Tags: f#

I checked the relevant [spec section](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597480) and guessed a few tries, but couldn't figure it out. How can I express, for example, the following light syntax recursive let binding using the non-light syntax (on a single line)?

```
let rec f x = g x 
and g x = f x
```

(`let rec f x = g x and g x = f x` gives me "Unexpected keyword 'and' in binding. Expected incomplete structured construct at or before this point or other token." unless I turn the light syntax off, as @Ramon Snir suggested, but surely there is a way to do this while the light syntax is on?)

Comment: This works fine as it is. FSI handled `let rec f x = g x and g x = f x` just fine (after `#light "off"`) and compiled correctly.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel - updated with my main try (other ones just included throwing `in`, `begin`, `end` and brackets around.

Comment: @Ramon Snir - very interesting, I'd be surprised if there turned out to be no way to do this while the light syntax is on.

Comment: This is a long-standing bug in F#, IMHO.

Comment: In the same way "let a = 2 let b = 3" will give you a parse error unless you turn light syntax off. Light syntax sometimes forces you to have line jumps. As Jon says, this "problem" is not new and I don't think there's a workaround (other than insert a line feed... which can be a good thing, after all).

Comment: @Laurent, I think a more accurate analogy for my question is that `let a = 2 in let b = 3 in ()` is non-light syntax which is valid both with `#light "off"` *and* `#light "on"`; I've never before seen valid non-light syntax which was invalid with `#light "on"`

Answer (score 3):

The same declaration as what @kvb suggests should work at the top-level as well:

```
#light "off"

module Foo = begin
  let rec f a = g (a + 1)
  and g a = f (a + 1)
end
```

Maybe the compiler is confused by some other code that follows your declarations?

**EDIT:** Oh, the problem is slightly different - you wanted to write the recursive declaration on a *single line* in the `#light` mode. I couldn't find any way to do that and I think it may not be possible in the `#light` mode. In practice you can always write multi-line declaration (even in some weird context):

```
if true && (let rec f x = g x
            and g x = f x in f) 0 then 
    printfn "funny"
```

Comment: Both snippits you and @kvb gave work fine for me, but aren't what I'm looking for. With `#light "on"`, I'd like to be able to write a recursive binding on a single line, which works fine with `#light "off"` without any extra syntax.

Comment: @Stephen - Ah, I understand the question now. Unfortunately, I don't think there is a way to do that (see edit for some details)

Answer (score 0):

What you've got is fine, but you're not done yet...  The form is `let rec [bindings] in [expr]`.  You've written the bindings, but no body.  You simply need to add `in` and then the expression in which you want the bindings to apply.  For example:

```
#light "off"

let rec even x =
    if x = 0 then true
    else odd (x-1)
and odd x =
    if x = 0 then false
    else even (x-1)
in
    printfn "%b" (even 20)
```

Comment: Thanks @kvb, but omitting the body isn't my problem here since I'm looking at top level bindings (I should have mentioned that). What I'd like to do is write the example expression I gave on a single line, and I figured there was a special non-light syntax for that, but what I have seen so far is that you can do it in one line without any extra syntax but you have to explicitly turn "off" the light syntax. Which surprises me, because in my experience until now all non-light syntax has been valid even when the light syntax is on. (sorry, lots of "ons" and "offs" here, might be hard to follow).

Comment: Not exactly what you're looking for, but I bet `let f,g=let rec f x=g x and g x=f x in f,g` works.

Comment: (Actually, probably a value restriction in this example.  Am AFK so can't try it now myself.)

Comment: @Brian - that works fine with `#light "off"`, but not with `#light "on"`

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your intent.  I don't think you can do `let rec ... and ...` on one line in "light" mode.